# Flickering Level Bar in Spigot/Minecraft Repeating Task

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I'm currently running into a rather annoying problem.

Im running round about this task, with a Spigot-1.8 in Java 1.8. But this exact code gives me two diffrent Results.

In one the Levelbar of Minecraft just counts down and in another the Levelbar just flickers every time it sets the new XP Value.

```
private static int buildTask;
private static int buildSeconds = 120;

public static void buildingTime() {
    buildTask = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Plugin.getInstance(), () -> {
        for (Player onlinePlayer : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            onlinePlayer.setLevel(buildSeconds);
        }

    //executing other Actions with Actionbar and Broadcasting Seconds to all players

    if (buildSeconds <= 0) {
        //ending here
    }

    buildSeconds--;
    }, 0, 20);
}
```

I'm using this Spigot: https://getbukkit.org/get/hNiHm0tuqAg1Xg7w7zudk63uHr0xo48D

Answer (score 0):

Already solved.... Let two tasks run at the same time which conflicted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).